# Print 'element1' in list returms an <Element 'element1' at 0x0000013C6D4B9270>

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, xml-parsing, elementtree

i started learning python recently and i have a problem with my code.
i am trying to parse an xml with elementtree that with the following form:

```
<UNHEATED_ROWS>6</UNHEATED_ROWS>
    <UNHEATED1 rid="1">
    </UNHEATED1>
    <UNHEATED2 rid="1">
    </UNHEATED2>
    <UNHEATED3 rid="1">
    </UNHEATED3>
    <UNHEATED4 rid="1">
    </UNHEATED4>
    <UNHEATED5 rid="1">
    </UNHEATED5>
    <UNHEATED6 rid="1">
```

with this:

```
for i in range root.iter('UNHEATED_ROWS'):
   uheatedzones = UNHEATED_ROWS.text
for j in range uheatedzones:
   uzones.append("UNHEATED" + str(j+1)):
for k in range(int(uheatedzones)):
   for uzones[k] in root.iter("UNHEATED%s" % (k+1)):
       print(uzones[k])
```

Instead of UNHEATED1,UNHEATED2... that i expected to get with the print i get
<Element 'UNHEATED1' at 0x0000017263D28220>

what is wrong with my code?
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the text of a **single** element, don't use any loop.
Use rather:

```
root.findtext('UNHEATED_ROWS')
```

Note however that the returned value is a **string**, not integer.

Another flaw in your code is `str(j+1)`.

The first wrong thing is that *j* is an object of *Element* class
and its conversion to string does not return its text.

The second wrong thing is `j+1`, i.e. you attempt to add *1* to this object.

To process correctly each *UNHEATED…* element, you can e.g. use *root.iter()*
(without parameters) and check in the loop whether the tag name starts with
"UNHEATED" and then it contains a digit (to omit *UNHEATED_ROWS* element).
You must import *re* module.

If you want to access **attributes** of an element, use *attrib* method of
an element, which returns a dictionary (*{attr_name: attr_value}*).

So example loop can be:

```
i = 0
for it in root.iter():
    if re.match(r'UNHEATED\d', it.tag):
        i += 1
        print(f'{i}: {it.tag}: {it.attrib["rid"]}')
```

For your source XML it prints:

```
1: UNHEATED1: 1
2: UNHEATED2: 1
3: UNHEATED3: 1
4: UNHEATED4: 1
5: UNHEATED5: 1
6: UNHEATED6: 1
```

Note also that I didn't use `it.text` in the above loop, since​ each
*UNHEATED…* element has no text and in this case *text* method returns
*None*.

Comment: please take a look at my answer,i couldnt post it as a comment. thank you

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answer.

```
<UNHEATED1 rid="1">
            <un_parameter1>82.8</un_parameter1>
            <un_parameter2>123.3720</un_parameter2>
            <ENVELOPE rid="1">
                <opaque_rows>17</opaque_rows>
                
                <transparent_column5>0.600,2.200,0.600,</transparent_column5>
                <transparent_column6>Α1,Α2,Α10,</transparent_column6>
                >
            </ENVELOPE>
</UNHEATED1>
```

each UNHEATED has a similar stracture and i want to access  for all UNHEATED, thats why i used the loop